# dataframe in R make empty and column after that

Tags: r, dataframe

I want to make an empty dataframe and after that add some columns,

Here the total number is not fixed so this is useless for me.

```
df <- data.frame(matrix(ncol = 1))
b<-"rang"
x <- c(b)
colnames(df) <- x
```

This is what I want to do

```
df <-data.frame()
df$rang<-0
```

This is the error i got `Error in $<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*, a, value = 0) :replacement has 1 row, data has 0`

How can I do that?

Comment: Is there a reason why you can't do `df <- data.frame(rang = 0)`? In almost ten years of using R I've never had to create an empty data.frame.

Comment: @Roland that name will be different  , i will give name to column as per the string i have in a Loop

Comment: @RonakShah  i want to make dynamic dataframe , where my code give me a string i want to add it into a dataframe , so at the end , i will have Dataframe with column Names  only

Answer (score 2):

Use a list like this:

```
colnames <- c("a", "b")
res <- list()

for (i in seq_along(colnames)) {
  res[[colnames[i]]] <- sample(1:10, i)
}

res <- as.data.frame(res)
```

Comment: Thanks Man , but read last comment , and make it like that please

Comment: I don't understand.

Answer (score 2):

What you seem to be after is a data frame with the column structure you need and where every vector in the data frame has a length of 0.

I've only occasionally needed such an object, and it typically involves some process where an earlier function returned a NULL value but my next process needs a data frame (perhaps it is looking for specific columns). Typically, I find that if I have to do this, my work flow is a little jacked up, but it can be a convenient hack to get around something quickly.

While you initially tried

```
df <-data.frame()
df$rang<-0
```

You'll find that the following works:

```
df <-data.frame()
df$rang <- numeric(0)
```

At this point, you're leveraging the functional nature of R, because you don't really care what type of column `df$rang` is, you can always change it later (or if you do know that it needs to be a character, use `character(0)`).

If you need to do this in bulk, you can do it with `replicate`

```
colnames <- c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e")
df <- replicate(length(colnames), numeric(0))
df <- as.data.frame(df)
names(df) <- colnames
df
```

Comment: now what if i want to add something like this `c(1,2,3,4,5)` in that particular column

Comment: That depends on if you want to initialize the data frame with 5 values (in which case, use `numeric(5)` instead), or if you want to append the data (in which case, you need to create a second data frame and `dplyr::bind_rows` the two data frames).  This is why I say that when I start doing things like this, I begin to wonder if my process is a little flawed.  Doing this doesn't usually lead to elegant solutions.